# What is the configuration to be inspectable iphone's inner app's WKwebview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm not a swift developer, but javascript developer.
As far as I know, to inspect the WKWebView by my iMac's safari,
there's gotta be some configurations for WKWebView.

So, that can make to be able to inspect my WKWebView.
But I don't know exactly about the name of it.

Anyone can help please?

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

For your information, I know the way to inspect.

As I mention it, I don't know the configuration exactly.

When I connect my iPhone and iMac, and open the iMac safari's developer menu.
There's nothing to inspect even my iPhone is running the WKWebView.
It's impossible to inspect that is the error.

Comment: https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter/issues/59

Comment: @HiteshBorse 
Seems that your saying is about `developerExtrasEnabled`.
I will find regarding that.
Thank you!